# How to return selected features with different feature selection models?

Tags: machine-learning, python, scikit-learn, feature-selection

I use the below function to detect the effect of those feature selection models on my data, it works perfectly.

what I want is to return the name of selected features for each model, is there any convincing way to do that based on my code?

```
def evaluating_model(fs, nm,model,X, y):
    pipe=Pipeline(steps=[('fs',fs),('sc',nm),('model', model)])
    scores = pd.DataFrame( 
        cross_validate(
            pipe,
            X,
            y,
            cv=KFold(n_splits=5, random_state=1, shuffle=True),
            scoring=["accuracy",'f1','recall','roc_auc','precision'],
            return_train_score=True,
            error_score='raise'
        )
    )

    #pipe.fit(X, y)
    #FS=pipe.named_steps['fs']
    #print(FS.ranking_)
    #print(FS.support_)

    return scores

featureSelection={  
  "f_classif":SelectKBest(score_func=f_classif, k=10),
  "rfe_RandomForest":RFE(estimator=RandomForestClassifier(), n_features_to_select=10),
  "sf_XGBClassifier":SelectFromModel(XGBClassifier(), max_features=10),
}
for keyFeature,valueFeature in featureSelection.items():
    evaluating_model(valueFeature,anyNormalizer,anyModel,X,y)
```

Comment: No, simply because the features in `X` don't have a name.
However they have a fixed index, which is much easier to return. Also you could store a vector of names yourself.

Comment: Thanks, @Erwan. I added some lines to my question as a comment; please check them. Those lines return the index of the Selected feature for `REF`. But I think It is the wrong implementation because the `Pipeline` inside `cross_validate` may choose different features. Am I correct? If not, please correct me. Also, any code explanation will be very useful.

Comment: Yes, the selected features can be different during the different runs of CV. I don't know what to suggest, I guess the feature selection should be done outside the CV if you want a single set of features for every model. Otherwise it can actually be useful to observe which features differ across CV runs, because these features are borderline and probably could be removed since apparently they are due to random variations.